# Viewing LiDAR datasets at lower zoom levels in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, lidar, zoom, point-cloud

Is there a way to display LiDAR datasets at lower zoom levels in ArcGIS Pro?

Currently, I can only see the point cloud at a zoom of around 1:800.

What I would like: view the point cloud/LiDAR dataset at much lower zoom levels in the Map & Map_3D views (i.e. - 1:20,000, 1:50,000 or greater).

What I have tried: Setting the Visibility Ranges under the Layer Properties -> General panel -> In Beyond/Out Beyond appear to do nothing but remove visibility entirely. Resetting each to None returns visibility back to the 1:800 zoom range.

Answer (score 2):

Raising the Display Limit on the LAS Dataset Layer -> Appearance tab (Point Thinning) allows display of the LiDAR Dataset at lower zoom levels.